# asp.net core - How to pass variable from controller to filter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller. On the controller's post method, there is a variable (an object variable) I want to pass to my action filter: the method:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)...
```

Any suggestions on how  achieve this?

Comment: If i understand your question, you are trying to access action method's parameter in action filter.

Can you try to access it from context's route values?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`HttpContext.Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_Items). It's a key / value collection that exists for the duration of a single request.

In your controller, add something:

```
HttpContext.Items["Something"] = "something I need later";
```

Then in the `OnActionExecuted` method pull it out:

```
var something = context.HttpContext.Items["Something"] as string;
```

Everything you pull out will be of type `object` so make sure you cast it to what it was.